# Meteor running on my own infrastructure

Tags: node.js, meteor, dedicated-server, dev-to-production

After reading the Meteor official documentation regarding this subjet, I would like to know if it's possible to change my code, deploy the new version, but without restarting the node js server? My idea is to have a development server, where I make my updates, and then after testing commit the changes to the real production server, so that I don't break anything.
If this doen't make any sense, what is the current best approach to accomplish the same results?

Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You should not need to reset the node js server. Any changes to the code will be injected into the client's browser.

From Meteor main page:

> ## Hot Code Pushes.
>
> Update your app while users are connected without disturbing them. When you push a new version, the new code is seamlessly injected into each browser frame in which the app is open.

Comment: Well, that I understand, but if you run meteor bundle myapp.tgz and you extract it, you will see that the files aren't exactly what you have on your Meteor app. If I want to change for instance a certain view, a html template, I could not found the exact file on the node.js project (production server).

Comment: Well you should not be editing stuff on the production server anyways.
Any changes should be done in development and then shipped to the production server as a bundle.

Comment: Exactly, so in order to place the new bundle on the production server without restarting it, I should do what? 
My development server I run with meteor (localhost,3000), and it's structured by me regarding a meteor project. But the production server was build with the result of meteor bundle, and it's a node.js project.

Comment: Also I found where the code is. It seems that the code is actually compressed and stored with a hashed filename.
"...bundle/static_cacheable/8ba004a49c3031bfc61281d8f7843dc7e03cb7eb.js"